# What is the meaning of following code line in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am reading a code of java source file. I see the following code lines given below

```
    GWT.runAsync(Overview.class, new LoadAsyncCallback() {
        public void onSuccess() {
            if (ApplicationDetails.class.getName().equals("1"))) 
            {
                 ...............
            }
```

**So my Point is**

```
 1. why it use ApplicationDetails.class file to access getName(). as 
    usually we use Java source file.

 2. GWT.runAsync(Overview.class, new LoadAsyncCallback() {
 what is the mean of this line.
```

even when I open ApplicationDetails sourse file i did not find any getName() method .

is there any difference to use class file or java sourse file

Comment: I suggest to also read some tutorials about [Retrieving Class Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) and [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Every `Class` in Java has [getName() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html).
2. Read about [code splitting in GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html).

Comment: but why it use .class file

Comment: It does not. It simply uses a name of that class.